# The named parameter 'Images' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, carousel

I'm new to flutter and try to build up image carousel using flutter. but now I'm getting below errors in my code. its occurring at  ImageCarousel class. you can find it on end of the code. how to fix them appreciate your help on this.

> The named parameter 'Images' isn't defined.
>
> The named parameter 'Images' isn't defined.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';


class GetStartedThree extends StatelessWidget {
  const GetStartedThree({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            ImageCarousel(),

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, bottom: 230),
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  child: Text('Meet \nYour Doctor\nHere', style: TextStyle(
                    height: 1.2,
                    fontFamily: 'Dubai',
                    fontSize: 35,
                    color: Color(0xffFAFAFA),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  ))),
            ),

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, top: 26),
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: Text('DOCTOR', style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Dubai',
                    fontSize: 30,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  ))),
            ),

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60),
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 320,
                    height: 65,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text('Get Started', style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 25,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                        ),
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                                Color(0xff05ABA3)),
                            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                              ),
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                  )
              ),
            ),

            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      height: 5,
                      width: 120,
                    )
                )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ImageCarousel extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ImageCarousel(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      Images: [
        AssetImage('assets/images/person1.png'),
        AssetImage('assets/images/person2.png'),
        AssetImage('assets/images/person3.png'),

      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for the carousel_slider package, you do not need an extra class for the carousel. All you need to do is use the CarouselSlider() widget and give it a map of image links :

```
final List<String> imgList = ['assets/images/person1.png',
                              'assets/images/person2.png',
                              'assets/images/person2.png',];

CarouselSlider(
  options: CarouselOptions(),
  items: imgList.map((item) => Container(
    child: Center(
        child:
        Image.asset(item, fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1000)),
  )).toList(),
),
```

Your full code would look like something like this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';

class GetStartedThree extends StatelessWidget {
  GetStartedThree({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final List<String> imgList = ['assets/images/person1.png',
                                'assets/images/person2.png',
                                'assets/images/person2.png',
                                ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            CarouselSlider(
            options: CarouselOptions(),
            items: imgList.map((item) => Container(
              child: Center(
                  child:
                  Image.asset(item, fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 1000)),
            )).toList(),
          ),

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, bottom: 230),
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  child: Text('Meet \nYour Doctor\nHere', style: TextStyle(
                    height: 1.2,
                    fontFamily: 'Dubai',
                    fontSize: 35,
                    color: Color(0xffFAFAFA),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  ))),
            ),

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, top: 26),
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: Text('DOCTOR', style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Dubai',
                    fontSize: 30,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  ))),
            ),

            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60),
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 320,
                    height: 65,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text('Get Started', style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 25,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                        ),
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                                Color(0xff05ABA3)),
                            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                              ),
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                  )
              ),
            ),

            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      height: 5,
                      width: 120,
                    )
                )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: actually its not clear to me. can you please tell  where I want to change my code

Comment: I changed the answer including the full code. Basically Images was not defined because you were passing it to your constructor without specifying it into your constructor. Turns out you dont need the extra class. Hope it helps.